# In Apache Spark, Is there concatenate RDD instead of a union?

Tags: apache-spark

both rdd.union() and ++ do union by eliminating duplicate objects in the RDD. I think this is an expensive way to concatenate two RDDs that are known to have distinct elements. What is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

> both rdd.union() and ++ do union by eliminating duplicate objects

You're wrong [`++`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@union(other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T])

> `def ++(other: RDD[T]): RDD[T]`
>
> Return the union of this RDD and another one. Any identical elements will appear multiple times (use .distinct() to eliminate them)

and [`union`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@union(other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]):

> `def union(other: RDD[T]): RDD[T]`
>
> Return the union of this RDD and another one. Any identical elements will appear multiple times (use .distinct() to eliminate them).

are not set union.

Same applies to `Dataset.union`.